# Exit parent Sub

Tags: vb.net, error-handling

I am a bit confused how to handle the errors in a VB .net app I am writing.

This is what I have:

```
Private Sub Func1()
 Try
   'stuff that could raise an error

 Catch ex As Exception
   MsgBox("There is an error" & ex)
   End
 End Try

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Func1()
 'a lot of stuff that will also raise an error is Func1 does
End Sub
```

This code will exit the application if there is an error.

If I remove the "End", it will go on and raise multiple errors in the Sub Button1_click.

So I need to put something in the Func1 that could interrupt execution the Sub Button1_click.

I could put Exit Sub but I have a lot of Subs that use this Func1 so I'd prefer a way to do it from Func1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to continue exection of Button1_Click if Func1 fails then change Func1 to a boolean Function

```
Private Function Func1() As Boolean
 Try
   'stuff that could raise an error

   Return True
 Catch ex As Exception
   MsgBox("There is an error" & ex)
   return False
 End Try

End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  if Func1() = True Then
     'a lot of stuff that will also raise an error is Func1 does
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't catch the exception at such a low level if all you want to do is show the text to the user.

Install a handler in the [`Application.ThreadException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and/or [`AppDomain.UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) events and do your `MsgBox` call there.

If you do that, there's no need for the `Try`/`Catch` block at all in `Func1` and, if an exception occurs, the remainder of `Func1` and `Button1_Click` don't run.